# Laravel, When database is empty I'm getting error otherwise not but I have to use this

Tags: laravel, undefined, offset

```
        $employee = Employee::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

            foreach (Company::all() as $company)
                {
                    if ($company->id == $employee[0]->company_id && $company->employee_active === 1)
                    {
                        $event->menu->add([
                            'text'        => 'Contracten',
                            'url'         => 'dashboard/contracts',
                            'icon'        => 'file-text',
                            'submenu' => [
                                [
                                    'text' => 'Contract opzetten',
                                    'url'  => 'dashboard/contracts/create',
                                    'icon_color' => 'red',
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]);
                    }
                }
```

**When I use this code I'm getting undefined offset: 0, if the database is empty. How can get this write? Should I use an if or something like that**

Comment: You should put  all of your `$company` logic in a simple `empty` check `if(!empty($employee)){ // then your logic of $employee[0] will make sense }`

Comment: Should I put  if(!empty($employee)){ inside the foreach or outside?

Comment: what is you logic in here? if the company of the connected user has `employee_active` attribute to 1 => add in menu ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Really you should configure your relationships correctly so that you can do

```
$companies = Company::all();

foreach($companies as $company){

    foreach($company->employees as $employee){

        if($employee->active){
          ....
        }   

    }

}
```

But in your case you can change your first line to

```
 $employee = Employee::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

Which will return an `Employee` object collection rather than an array so you don't need to use an `[index]` to get the first object.

Comment: it's a bad solution to cycle through all the companies and then get all there employee.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe solution is correct. You can make an eager loading of companies and employees to avoid N+1 query problem. There is an official example of this case:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading